# Как обратиться к кастомному ресурсу WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Подскажите как я могу обратиться к кастомному ресурсу "isShowCheck" моего объекта.

```
<CheckBox>
    <CheckBox.Resources>
        <sys:Boolean x:Key="isShowCheck">true</sys:Boolean>
    </CheckBox.Resources>
</CheckBox>
```

есть у меня ресурс со стилями и я вот пытаюсь достучаться

```
<Style TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding Path=Resources[isShowCheck]}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: А почему у вас за функционал отвечает XAML? Если хотите добавить функционал, то делайте свойство расширения, а не ресурсы, они для этого совершенно не предназначены.

Comment: А где вы тут увидели расширение функционала, мне нужно создать более 100 000 кастомных объектов со своими триггерами и изменяемым поведением, если я каждый буду обрабатывать программно то на это уйдёт куча памяти.

Comment: `А где вы тут увидели расширение функционала` - ну, вы делаете некую переменную за пределами контрола, по значению которой меняется вид, разве это не расширение функционала? Как по мне, еще какое. `более 100 000 кастомных объектов` - и в чем проблемы? Делаете коллекцию, привязываете к ней `ItemsControl`, настраиваете виртуализацию, радуетесь. Да и 100к это не так уж и много. `каждый буду обрабатывать программно` - обрабатывать что? Искать ресурс в коде? Ну так это вы не должны вообще хотеть делать, вы вообще не должны в коде обращаться к контролам!

Comment: Сделайте юзерконтрол, не мучайтесь)

Comment: @aepot идея хорошая к которой и пришёл прям вот пару минут назад)